# connection string in code file

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I used the following class file to create connection string

```
namespace connect
{
    public class connection
    {
        string constr = "Data Source=.\\MYSQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Kuldeep\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\final\\App_Data\\information1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";   
        public string constring
        {

                get
                {    
                    return constr;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
```

I want to call this string in my code file like this.

```
public partial class Account_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);

    }
    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(string constring);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from User where UserName =@UserName and Password=@Password", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPWD.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
          //  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
        }  
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

What is the code syntax to call the connection string in code file??

Comment: It's not really a good idea to compile settings like the connectionstring into your dll. Better use app.config or web.config for this. If you do want to proceed with this approach, make the class or property static and call it like this: `connection.constring`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use static class

```
public static class Connection
{

....

}
```

And call this code to invoke your connection

```
var connection = Connection.Constring;
```

For your case :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection.Constring);
```

Note :

1. I suggest you to use Uppercase naming of your class and properties
2. I suggest you to use using block arround connection and command object

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.80).aspx

1. Another link about externalisation of your string conenction by using `ConfigurationManager class`

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i just tried it.. but doesnt work..

Comment: Just verify your case of class and methods

Comment: thank u..@frederique.. but now m going to another way.. using config file..

Comment: Happy to help you It's best practise Patel, yes you can use ConfigurationManager class

Comment: Read this link Patel it's also interessant : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use App.config file to set your db credentials.

Steps to use App.config

1.First of all add App.config file which is an xml file

2.Add below given code to app.config file

```
 <

?xml version="1.0"?>
        <configuration>
          <appSettings>
            <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=.\\MYSQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Kuldeep\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\final\\App_Data\\information1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;"/>
          </appSettings>
         </configuration>
```

3.Add the namespace "using System.Configuration;" ,if namespace is not avilable you should add the dll "System.Configuration" ,then use the below code

```
 string con = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
```

Comment: ya now i used it..like this..<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=.\\MYSQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Kuldeep\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\final\\App_Data\\information1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: Good.. ie is also one of the way for adding connection string